# How to position a label in the center of a leaflet tile?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have statistical data by leaflet tile. I try to put a label in the center of a tile so that it roughly looks like this:

[image]

So far I have code like this:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 512px; width: 512px;border: solid;">
</div>

...
var textLatLng = [?, ?]; // This is my question, how to calculate this?

var myTextLabel = L.marker(textLatLng, {
    icon: L.divIcon({
        className: 'text-labels',   
        html: '173'
    }),
    zIndexOffset: 1000     
});
myTextLabel.addTo(map);
```

Got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22500570/382009)

Comment: How do you know which piece of "statistical data" to display? (i.e. how do you know the text to render?)

Comment: I have locations converted into tile number x and y for zoom level 1-18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to extend a [`GridLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#gridlayer) and its `createTile` method to display your data. Something like this, assuming a synchronous lookup

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.8583736, 2.2922926], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


var GridInfo = L.GridLayer.extend({

    // called for each tile
    // return a DOM node containing whatever you want
    createTile: function (coords) {

        // create a div
        var tile = document.createElement('div');
        tile.className = "infotile";
        tile.style.outline = '1px solid black';

        // lookup the piece of data you want
        // replace with whatever you use
        var data = lookup(coords.x, coords.y, coords.z);

        // let's add the lat/lng of the center of the tile
        var tileBounds = this._tileCoordsToBounds(coords);
        var center = tileBounds.getCenter();

        tile.innerHTML = '<span>' + data+
            '<br>'+
            'lat:'+ center.lat+' '+'lng:'+center.lng+
        '</span>';

        return tile;
    }
});

map.addLayer(new GridInfo());
```

And a demo

```js
function lookup(x, y, z) {
    return "x:"+x+", y:"+y+" at zoom "+z;
}


var map = L.map('map').setView([48.8583736, 2.2922926], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


var GridInfo = L.GridLayer.extend({

    // called for each tile
    // returns a DOM node containing whatver ypu want
    createTile: function (coords) {

        // create a div
        var tile = document.createElement('div');
        tile.className = "infotile";
        tile.style.outline = '1px solid black';

        // lookup the piece of data you want
        var data = lookup(coords.x, coords.y, coords.z);

        // let's add the lat/lng of the center of the tile
        var tileBounds = this._tileCoordsToBounds(coords);
        var center = tileBounds.getCenter();

        tile.innerHTML = '<span>' + data+
            '<br>'+
            'lat:'+ center.lat+' '+'lng:'+center.lng+
        '</span>';

        return tile;
    }
});

map.addLayer(new GridInfo());
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.infotile {display: flex;}
.infotile span {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>
 
 <div id='map'></div>
```